# Scroll to Anchor jumps back to start

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, anchor

Im a JS-beginner so i took this Code out of the Internet and i have some Problems with it. firstly, It always jump back to beginning of div if it scrolls up. Secondly if the browserwindow is smaller than the main wrapper, the content div jumps to the left and hide the Menu. Better to see it:

http://clan.morphium-gw2.de/nina/

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks

`$(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var target = this.hash,
                $target = $(target);
                    $('#container').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
                    }, 2000, 'swing', function () {
                    window.location.hash = target;
                    });
            });
        });`

Answer (score 0):

could you try to debug and see the error it show,
print the value of target variable,and try to make a console.log(target) 
let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

i found a syntax error into your script
change this :

```
<body onLoad="BilderVorladen('images/a1.jpg','images/a2.jpg','images/a3.jpg',,'images/a4.jpg');">
```

for this :

```
<body onLoad="BilderVorladen('images/a1.jpg','images/a2.jpg','images/a3.jpg','images/a4.jpg');">
```